# Kafka connect standalone - Could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone
I get this error when I try to run connect-standalone in kafka.

First I realized that there was no connect folder in the libexec where this file was, I downloaded that. Still the same error.

So I tried to compile ConnectStandalone.java file separately, and I saw that a lot of packages are missing from my folder of kafka. There were supposed to be connect and common folders with some packages in org/apache/kafka but there weren't.
Package org.slf4j is also missing.

I tried to download a few manually, but if someone could tell me where I can get the correct folder.

All I want to do is to create a simple kafka producer that reads a csv and sends it line by line to a consumer.

Please tell me if I am at least heading in the correct direction.

EDIT: I used brew to download kafka, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the kafka install has incomplete binaries. To have producer consumer of csv file. You can run sample thing as an example from Linux machine.

Assuming kafka borker is at `localhost:9092` and zookeeper at `localhost:2181`, Open 2 console and go to kafka home

In first console create topic `test`:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Then open as consumer in that console by:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

In second console send csv data to test topic:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test < abc.csv
```

See on first console the csv data consumed.

If above commands also not running then you need a fresh re-install of kafka and zookeeper.